# Stretchy Headers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'd like to implement a Stretchy Header Functionality as seen in this GIF:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/nrjio/Stretchy-480.gif

Currently, what I do on **iPhones WebView** is to call a Scope Function On Scroll (esp. focusing on Rubberband Scrolling) and Adjust the Image Height utilising CSS Calc Function, like so:

**VIEW:**

```
/* Call a Function on Scroll to Enlarge, and on Release to Reset Header.  */

<ion-content on-scroll="onScroll()" on-release="onRelease()">


//Actual Image to be Scrolled when Rubberband Scrolling up, similarly to the GIF: 

<div id="header_image" ng-style="{'background' : url('someimage.jpg') center center', 'width' : '100%', 'height' : 'calc(40% + '+dynamic_height+'px)'}"></div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.onScroll = function() {

 //Only do funny stuff when Overscrolling on iOS

 if ($ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition().top < 0)
 {
   //Adjust Height of Header by Scrolled Value
   $scope.dynamic_height = ($ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition().top*-1);
   $scope.$apply();
 }
};
```

*(Note this Setup uses Ionic Framework and Angular JS. This is however not much of relevance to a General Solution to this Issue)*

I haven't yet implemented the Release Function which is supposed to be run, when the User lets go of the Scrolling, and resets the Header image to the initial height *(in this case: 40%+0px)*.

This current Solution is not properly working as the Content resets scroll Position to 0 each time we overscroll, thus resulting in Flickering. I'd be willing to setup a Codepen, but maybe someone can come up with a ready solution already?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, someone already came up with a possible [solution](http://codepen.io/olach/pen/NqrYQL).
`header.style[ionic.CSS.TRANSFORM] = 'translate3d(0,'+translateAmt+'px,0) scale('+scaleAmt+','+scaleAmt+')';`